# How to COUNTIFS with an array of criteria and match NOT condition?

Tags: excel, formula

[image]

My data table is like the image above. I can easily count the number of **Male** participants in group **B** or **C** using this array formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($B:$B, $E3, $C:$C, $F3:$F4))
```

The result is **3** as expected. However I'm gonna do the reverse thing, that is count the number of **Male** participants in *NOT* group **B** or **C**. The result should be **1** but currently I'm stuck at this.

Can anybody show me a way please (preferably not just counting the number of all **Male** participants and then do a subtraction)? I have even tried to change the values in the **Group** to something like **<>B** and **<>C** but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, the thing with the formula right now is that the first `COUNTIFS` (for F3) will return 2 and the second `COUNTIFS` (for F4) will return 3, which `SUM` converts into 5 when you try:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($B:$B, $E3, $C:$C, "<>"&$F3:$F4))
```

I would suggest using `SUMPRODUCT` instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B:$B=$E3)*($C:$C<>$F3)*($C:$C<>$F4))
```

And maybe make the range smaller since this can take some time (you don't need to insert this as an array formula).

Otherwise, another option would be to count all the Males, and then subtract the counts for group B and subsequently C:

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B, $E3)-SUM(COUNTIFS($B:$B, $E3, $C:$C, $F3:$F4))
```

Comment: Hmm, after trying the formulas, I think I would go with the simple solution by subtracting the total number with the counted one. Anyway, thank you very much for you and *barry houdini* help and wish you all a happy new year too.

Comment: @user433531 You're welcome and Happy New Year to you as well :)

Answer (score 4):

As you only have 2 in the group you can easily use COUNTIFS with 2 separate criteria, i.e.

`=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$E3,$C:$C,"<>"&$F3,$C:$C,"<>"&$F4)`

but clearly that might not be desirable for a large group, so you could use `SUMPRODUCT` like this to reference the group once

`=SUMPRODUCT(($B:$B=$E3)*ISNA(MATCH($C:$C,$F3:$F4,0)))`

`ISNA` will exclude matching rows - to include use `ISNUMBER`

You can replace F3:F4 with any single row or column of values

Note: whole columns with SUMPRODUCT will work (post Excel 2003) but is undesirable as Jerry says